# Please help me with this annoying navigation

Tags: 18.04

I don't know what I did, but something changed the navigation..

Normally when I click on an app, it is supposed to display on top of each other..

for example, firefox and terminal, the terminal should be on top on firefox

but now, when I click on the terminal, it will focus on the terminal and then firefox will be minimized away! this is so annoying..

It's like..I have firefox and a terminal open, then when I click on the terminal firefox will go away and the focus is on the terminal and when I click on firefox the terminal will go away and the focus is on the terminal

I want it to be normal again, when I have firefox open, and I click on the terminal, the terminal should be displayed on top of firefox, firefox is not minimized..

I tried to upload screenshots, but they were too big, I tried imageshack and then the file format was not supported...I tried uploading the video to my google drive but even google drive says my video format is not supported

I want to upload graphics to help with understanding but it seems i couldn't ...

Hopefully what I said above is clear enough..

Comment: Have you rebooted? Sometimes a glitch magically goes away.

Comment: does it only affect those two applications?

Comment: it's been solved by restarting :) haha....omg  ...but this would've never happened on windows..